# Arranging 10 people in a row

Tags: combinatorics

let there be 10 people, how many ways are there to arrange them in a row when man A and

man B need to sit next to each other, and man C and man D should not sit near each other.

is it $9!*2!-7!*2!$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume we have a fat man $AB$ or a fat man $BA$, we have $9$ men and $9!\cdot 2!$ possibilities. Sometimes we have a fat man $CD$ or a fat man $DC$, we have $8$ men and $8!\cdot 2!\cdot 2!$ possibilities to subtract. The answer is 
$$
2!\cdot 9!-8!\cdot 2!\cdot 2!.
$$

Comment: I get it all except why the 2! of AB is outside?

Comment: I am going rewrite the answer.

Comment: ok so why 8!2! I know but why another 2!?

Comment: We have two fat men: first 2! for AB and BA, the second for CD and DC.

Comment: Sorry I still do not get it, if  AB and BA is 2! so CD and DC need to be 2! but not 2!2!

Comment: Let .. denote some people. We count: ..AB..CD.., ..AB..DC.., ..BA..CD.., ..BA..DC.. --- we have 2! for first choice, and 2! for second one. We should do both choices and we have 2!2! variants.

Comment: got it thanks!!!